# SPF with -all includes directive with ~all?

Tags: spf

I want to update and simplify the SPF record of my domain. Unfortunately, http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax is unclear.

My domain uses one MX relay for receiving and sending. The SPF rule is then as simple as this `v=spf1 mx -all`. This will forbid sending mails from any other sources.

The problem I have is that one user uses it's provider (belgacom.be) for outgoing mail relay. The provider's current SPF rule is the following : `v=spf1 mx include:ispmail.spf.secure-mail.be include:bgc.spf.secure-mail.be include:bgcpartners.spf.secure-mail.be ~all`

I'm tempted to define my SPF rule as `v=spf1 mx include:belgacom.be -all`, but it is unclear what the `~all` in the included SPF rule will do. The rules included by belgacom.be's rule also have a `~all`. Will the `~all` in the included rules be considered as a match and will my `-all` be ignored ?

**Edit**: Found the testing tool http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html. By adding the `include:belgacom.be` I get `Permanent Error SPF Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookups`. The question on the included `~all`remains open.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-5.2 is pretty clear

Comment: @Håkan Lindqvist The table makes the answer very clear. Thanks for the link. If you provide an answer, I'll validate it. Or I may delete the answer if you prefer.

Comment: what about `v=spf1 mx mx:belgacom.be include:ispmail.spf.secure-mail.be include:bgc.spf.secure-mail.be include:bgcpartners.spf.secure-mail.be -all`? Note that you need to regularly check the upstream's SPF records then.

Comment: To optimize SPF filtering (avoid DNS queries) I used ip addresses only. I also replaced the mx with my ip4 and ip6 addresses. For belgacom.be I used `ip4:195.238.0.0/19`. This seam good enough. I don't know if they have ipv6 addresses.

Comment: Almost the same question: [What does a “-all” do in an included (secondary) SPF record?](https://superuser.com/q/1167143/61370)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`include`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) mechanism in SPF is a bit of a misnomer in that it does not actually include the referenced record's contents into the main record.

Instead the referenced record is evaluated separately and its `pass`/`fail` result is reinterpreted as the `include` being a `match` or a `not match` (no longer `pass`/`fail`!).
(See the conversion table in [`include` section of the SPF spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) for all the cases.)

Thus, just like for other mechanisms, it's the optional qualifier prefix (default `+`) to the `include` which determines what it actually means when the mechanism matches.

Simple non-`include` example:

- `ip4:192.0.2.1` (aka `+ip4:192.0.2.1`) means that if the IPv4 address of the client is `192.0.2.1`, then the result is `pass`.
- `-ip:192.0.2.1` means that if the IPv4 address of the client is `192.0.2.1`, then the result is `fail`.

`include` example:

- `include:foo.example.com` (aka `+include:foo.example.com`) means that if the evaluation of the SPF record at `foo.example.com` resulted in `pass`, this means that the `include` is a match, so the result is set according to the qualifier of this `include`, hence `pass`.
- `-include:foo.example.com` means that if the evaluation of the SPF record at `foo.example.com` resulted in `pass`, this means that the include is a match, so the result is set according to the qualifier of this `include`, hence `fail`.